# PHP MySQL foreach loop problem

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

When using the foreach loop for two variables in an array, the MySQL query returns the first array variable along with the second during the second loop for some strange reason. Would anyone know what the cause of this is? Does the cache need to be cleared or any variables need to be cleared?

```
$db_array = array($id1,$id2);
foreach ($db_array as &$db_id) {

//MySQL code here

}
unset($db_id);
```

Comment: You probably need to show us some code *(and the result you get, and what you expect)*, for us to understand your problem

Comment: Second loop... I only see one here? A better code example might enable us to actually help.

Answer (score 0):

Move the **unset($db_id);** at the end of the foreach(), so it would be

```
$db_array = array($id1,$id2);
foreach ($db_array as &$db_id) {

//MySQL code here

unset($db_id);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have a **&** with $db_id? (is there something I don't know about php?)

Comment: It's the pass-by-reference operator in PHP - here it lets you change the array elements as you iterate over them.